# How does this HTML method = "POST" tag work?

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-requests, python-requests-html

I recently started a project that was going to download some data from a certain site. Unfortunately, when I wanted to download html with r.text, I got this code instead of the code I expected:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Working...</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="some link"><input type="hidden" name="wa" value="wsignin1.0" /><input type="hidden" name="wresult" value="some links tokens and certificates" /><input type="hidden" name="wctx" value="some link" /><noscript><p>Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.</p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></noscript></form>
    <script language="javascript">
        window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()', 0);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I open this html code in webbrowser it redirects me to a certain site.

Can I send request with python requests module that will work just like that ?

---

*If I did not explain something enough, I would be grateful to write it in a comment.*

Comment: Please show the code you've written so far and make sure to include the URL that you're trying to work with

Comment: My code actually just logs in to this page and downloads this html code. I used this code to download it:

```requests.get('https://somesite.com', 
             headers={'user-agent': Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36 OPR/79.0.4143.73''},
             allow_redirects=True)
```

Comment: @BrutusForcus  ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Comment: That's not a real URL. You need to present code that reproduces the issue

Comment: @BrutusForcus 
This url contains confidential data. Is there any pattern to send this form with requests ?

Comment: It seems possible that the page you're working with is managed in part by Javascript. Try the *selenium* module

Comment: Yes, Selenium will most likely work, but I want this bot to be fast and ram-low. @BrutusForcus

Comment: I mabe should try recording network and opening this html code with webbrowser

Comment: it looks like that this request **Content-Type** is **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

Comment: @BrutusForcus ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Comment: Ok, I was able to fix this problem. Thank you @BrutusForcus for help